# Windows 10 - Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 2021.007.20099 issue black screen

Tags: windows-10, adobe-acrobat, adobe-air

I try to open a new window from my AIR application where inside there's a generated PDF.

My operating system is Windows 10

My Adobe Acrobat Reader DC version is 2021.007.20099

When I try to open the windows, inside it I've only a black screen as follow [image: Result of open PDF]

I'm trying to debug my code, so I've as PdfCapability the code 3202.

In order I've tried:

1. Update to latest version my Adobe Acrobat Reader DC
2. Try to repair my installation
3. Uninstall and re-install the Adove Acrobat Reader DC
4. I've removed the check from menu Edit -> Preference -> Security (Advance) from the security sandbox group

The result is the same

Answer (score 0):

I've found a possible solution.

On this [site](https://borncity.com/win/2021/10/30/adobe-acrobat-reader-dc-21-007-20099-64-bit-download-fehlerhaft/) write the version in object of my question presents bugs, so I've installed from [Adobe site](https://get.adobe.com/it/reader/otherversions/) the previous version released for Windows 10, so the PDF will be opened without problems.